# Automator Sending Email With Incomplete Table Before MySQL Query Finishes

Tags: mysql, macos, email, automator

I don't know if this is in need of a MySQL fix or an Automator fix, but I have a query that generally takes around five minutes to run and save to my tmp folder -- which a simplified version looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.txt';
```

From there, I have an Automator script Folder Action that grabs whatever file hits the 'tmp' folder, attaches it to an email, and sends it to the email address I designate. This works when the SQL query runs in a second or so, but it basically sends a blank .txt when the query takes a bit to run because it's sending it as soon as the file is created in the folder.

Is there any way to either stop SQL from creating the table in the folder until the query is completed? Or a way to tell Automator to not send the email until it's fully downloaded? I know I can use a delay function in Automator but I'd rather figure out something that can handle different query lengths if possible.

Please let me know if I can provide any other information that's helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Chances are excellent that this is a Mail issue.  All of us that script Mail have been forced to use delays in our scripts to allow enough time for an attachment to be fully ready.  My theory is that this is GCD problem, and that the multithreaded background architecture is allowing Mail to mess with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it seems like you just need to know how long the query's going to take to run and then build a `delay` into Automator/AppleScript before it starts running.